# Slider JavaScript Sumindo

Tags: javascript, carousel

Boa tarde gente, será que poderiam me ajudar.
Estou colocando no site que estou desenvolvendo um slider bem simples para apenas passar 3 imagens. o exemplo eu pegue no site w3school.
Mas conforme ele vai passando as imagens, na hora que ele chega na ultima ele some e depois de um tempão ele retorna. 
O que será que acontece? Alguém tem alguma sugestão?
Segue o codigo que estou usando.

-- Um problema que identifiquei é que estou tentando usar 4 sliders iguais na mesma pagina, pois quando tirei os outros 3 o primeiro funcionou, o que eu faço pra poder usar os 4 slider na mesma pagina?

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myCarousel2");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section">
  <img class="myCarousel2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
  <img class="myCarousel2" src="./img/efloor/gerencial_slider.png">
  <img class="myCarousel2" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
</div>
<!--Slider 2-->
```

Comment: Você não fez alteração nenhuma no código? Eu testei esse código e funcionou bem.

Comment: Pior que não! Não estou entendo o porque dele esta fazendo isso.

Comment: No seu exemplo aqui em cima está funcionando normalmente, não?

Comment: Qual navegador você está usando?

Comment: aparentemente esta. Estou usando o mozilla e o chrome.

Comment: bom eu descobri o que acontece, estou tentando usar 4 sliders desse na mesma pagina, pelo que pesquisei esta dando conflito tem como arrumar?

Comment: uso o Opera e funcionou normal aqui

Comment: Não está ocorrendo erro nenhum no código, nem com 4 slides, [veja o exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/n6ncsdx2/), não entendi o problema?

Comment: Gente obrigada a todos que tentaram ajudar, tinha um conflito com outro script, no momento que retirei o mesmo todos os slides funcionaram corretamente. Obrigada a Todos :)